# Default unit in qgis and how to change it

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have a polygon layer in qgis and I want to know that

1. what is the default unit of scale of the layer?
2. Either it is in inches or meters?
3. How can i change it?
4. If it is in inches and i convert it to meter then will this
   automatically scale the polygon to meters?

Comment: "Each polygon has each of its vertices defined by a pair of coordinates. Leaving the geographical component aside, these coordinates would be dimensionless. The geographical component is established by assigning a Coordinate Reference System to the layer. Reprojecting features from one system to another modifies their coordinates." This is not an answer, just a motivation to start researching.

Answer (score 3):

1. The default unit of scale will be dependent on the layers's CRS. It's the CRS that defines the meaning of the coordinates values.
2. You could check that in layer's properties or CRS definition.
3. You can change it by transforming the layer to other CRS. Simply save the layer as new file with new CRS. If you want the measurements to be expressed in meters, simply switch units in Settings>Options>Map Tools> Preferred distance units.
4. The 'on the fly' transformation will convert it to your map window CRS. If it is in meters it will automatically fit. For speed and accuracy reasons it is best to have consistency in layer's and project's CRS. Also most processing algorithms require consistent CRS between analysed layers.